# Captive Portal for my Website Served off of the Same Device as Access Point is Served

Tags: raspbian, networking, sense-hat

I currently have a Raspberry Pi 3 equipped with a SenseHat running Raspbian. I Have made a website to control the SenseHat by running programs that use the SenseHat. My server is nothing fancy:). I needed a way to demonstrate my Raspberry Pi SenseHat website so I have my RPi configured as a wireless access point. I feel the next part is to make a captive portal so that I don't have to tell people to punch a long IP address into their phones when they want to control the SenseHat. Their are tutorials to do this but it doesn't seem to work captive portal to 172.24.1.1:1234. Their are tutorials to show me how to do this with lighttpd, I could do this but then I would have a Splash page with a link to my SenseHat Library Homepage and from that page their would be a link to the actual page you can run the SenseHat from(Seems a long ways around when you could go straight to the SenseHat Library HomePage!). I am sure their is a way to do this can anyone help?

Comment: So is your end goal to redirect all users to a captive pages to have them agree to some sort of terms and services?

Comment: No I want to bring them to a Home Page for my SenseHat Library Programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend doing this with a small set of iptables rules redirecting all traffic to port 80 and 443 to your home page.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
```

An example with the ip's that you have provided being:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.24.1.1:24
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.24.1.1:24
```

Additionally you should have your HTTP server configured to redirect every unknown URL to its start page. So that if a user enters `http://www.awesomepeople.com/Mohammad-Ali` you don't get a 404 from your sense hat web server. This would in essence redirect them to `172.24.1.1:24/Mohammad-ali`.

What the IP tables rules above are doing in essence is redirecting all traffic to your web server which in this case is your sense hat page, so if I where connected to your network and entered in any domain at all, i would be redirected to your page.

Comment: would there be some way to do this with the dnsmasq configuration?

Comment: @RPImaniac probably, but the problem with using the dns is caching, odds are that a lot of people will have their website dns cached which means that it won't hit your dns but instead would have the IP in memory.

Comment: Does this mean that if someone connect to my wifi then they will be rerouted to whatever page I set?

Comment: @RPImaniac exactly, and also please remember to mark this answer as correct if it has helped you

Comment: should I mark it as correct now or after ive tried it and it works or is this a question for meta

Comment: @RPImaniac you mark it as correct when you believe that it is the correct answer and will solve your problem, this is done to inform others that this is a valid answer and you may remove this as the correct answer if it does not work after you have tried it

Comment: If this doesn't work as it, check with `sudo iptables -t nat -L --line-numbers -n` to see if  where it has ended up in relation to any rules related to the access point; you may have to work them into that or use `-I` appropriately.  (It should be fine IMO, since I don't think an AP should require any other PREROUTING rules, but the question doesn't get into details about how it was done...).  Note also this means *all* web traffic via the AP, regardless of intended domain, will end up coming to the pi's server instead.  Of course, that is what a "captive portal" does.

Comment: will this always make it redirect to that page or will it only redirect the first time

Comment: @RPImaniac this will always redirect to that page, please mark this answer as correct if it has helped you.

Comment: Just for the info this is the site I followed to get wifi working on mi RPi. https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

Comment: @RPImaniac part 1 the http server part isn't about how you configured your server. It is about how you want people to be redirected. Here let me give you a hypothetical example. Imagine I connected to your access point, then I entered `Google.com` or any other domain into my web browser. Now instead of taking me to google I would be redirected to your site which is located at `172.24.1.1:1234`. But now instead imagine that I entered `google.com/Mohammad-is-my-hero` Instead of being able to see how I am a hero I would instead by shown `172.24.1.1:1234/Mohammad-is-my-hero`

Comment: @RPImaniac part 2 which would in turn depending on how your server is configured display a 404 page which may cause confusion amongst users

Comment: Oh I see! So I would want my 404 error page to be the SenseHat Library HomePage

Comment: @RPImaniac yes that would be most optimal or a page that explains to the user what is happening would also be a great choice

Comment: @MohammadAli will configuring the iptables in this way prevent me from using internet on the raspberry pi

Comment: @RPImaniac yes the pre routing rule will redirect all traffic to your captive portal

Comment: @MohammadAli how do you undo this command

Comment: @RPImaniac you can find some instructions at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules